# Odoo Element "barcode" cannot be located in parent view

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I try to add Map Price filed after Barcode on Product Page,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="product_template_map_price_label" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//*[@name='barcode']" position="after">
                    <div class="map-price" groups="base.group_user">
                        <span class="oe_currency_value" name="map_price" groups="base.group_user"/>
                        <label for="map_price" groups="base.group_user">Map Price:</label>
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

But always receive error

```
Element '<xpath expr="//*[@name=&#39;barcode&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

Element Xpath:

[image]
[image]

I trying to change different xpath, but receive the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `barcode` field is not defined in the `product_template_form_view` form, you can try [product_template_only_form_view](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/product/views/product_template_views.xml#L45)